# My TextView is not showing....Why?

Tags: android, listview, footer

I am trying to create a ListView with a TextView immediately under it.  To accomplish this I am adding a footer to the ListView.  I want a line between the ListView and the TextView, but I want it to have specific margins.  I have created a style and then add it to the footer.  When I add the view with the style it pushes my text in the completely off the screen.  Here is the ListView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view_order_filter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/orderFilters"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:text="@string/order_filter" >
      </Button>

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/orderFiltersCancel"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:text="@string/cancel" >
      </Button>
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearyLayout>
```

Here is my style:

```
<style name="divider">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
</style>
```

And here is my footer:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View style="@style/divider" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="@string/total"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orderTotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot of what my view is looking like.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LinearLayout in your footer is horizontal but View with style="@style/divider"  has layout_width:match_parent. It pushes everything that comes afterwards off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with your "match_parent" in @style/divider

{

```
<item name="android:layout_width">20dp</item>

<item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>

<item name="android:layout_marginRight">15dp</item>

<item name="android:layout_marginLeft">15dp</item>

<item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>

<item name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
```

}

Try this you will be able to see your view,after this adjust the width according to your need

All you can make your linear layout as vertical

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="40dp" >

<View style="@style/divider" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="12000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code. here i merged your main xml and footer in single file. Edit it according to you

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view_order_filter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderFilters"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="order_filter" >
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderFiltersCancel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="cancel" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>



    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="total"
            android:textColor="#3a6e9a"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orderTotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="left"
            android:textColor="#3a6e9a" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```